# How to loop through columns and retrieve column values?

Tags: sql, oracle, cursor

I have a question regarding Oracle cursor.

I need to compare the values in a selected list of columns, see which records have changed after update. The table is huge, the only way to distinguish between new and old record is by the Batch_ID.

The output table will include these information:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICBkG.jpg)

So i have something very basic like below, except that i need to  write like hundreds of SELECT statement in order to go through hundreds of columns.

```
SELECT a.*, b.LAST_name AS last_name_updated --- here the variable could be ethnicity, income category etc..
from (SELECT person_id, last_name
      FROM   person  
      WHERE batch_id = (select max(batch_id) from person)
     ) a FULL OUTER JOIN
     (SELECT person_id, last_name
      FROM   person  
      WHERE batch_id = (select max(batch_id) - 1 from person)
     ) b
     ON a.person_id = b.person_id
WHERE  nvl(a.last_name,0) <> nvl(b.last_nm,0)
```

I need to go through a list of about 500 field name like Income, Race, Last_Name etc and capture all the changes, if any, in all these columns.

how do i go about this without writing hundreds of these `SELECT` statements?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: here is the base SQL query.  SELECT a.*, b.LAST_name AS last_name_updated
from
 (SELECT person_id, last_name
 FROM   person  
 WHERE batch_id = (select max(batch_id) from person)
 )  a
FULL OUTER JOIN
 (SELECT person_id, last_name
 FROM   person  
 WHERE batch_id = (select max(batch_id) - 1 from person)
 )  b
ON a.person_id = b.person_id
WHERE  nvl(a.last_name,0) <> nvl(b.last_nm,0)

Comment: I only work with SQL server, but in Oracle there must be a system table that stores all of this. Look in the master database. You can then query that to get any info about any object in your database.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  A cursor is probably not needed for this purpose.

Comment: @GordonLinoff you're like a StackOverflow god! Good job on all those points. You must have helped many many people.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelZ... I'm trying to capture all the value change in each column of interest and build a table to store all the before and after value.

Comment: @MichaelZ. "Look in the master database" Oracle doesn't have a master database, but does provide data dictionary views.

Answer (score 1):

This is a generic SQL statement that will use ALL_TAB_COLS to generate a SQL statement that can be used to compare columns:

```
  SELECT    CASE WHEN column_id = '1' THEN q'[ select 'batchid: ' || batchid ]' END
         || CASE
                WHEN column_name <> 'BATCHID'
                THEN
                       q'[ || case when ]'
                    || column_name
                    || q'[<> lag(]'
                    || column_name
                    || q'[) over (partition by batchid order by col1, col2) then ' ]'
                    || column_name
                    || ' has changed'' end'
            END
         || CASE WHEN column_id = MAX (column_id) OVER () THEN q'[ as changemessage from testtable]' END
             sql
    FROM all_tab_cols a
   WHERE table_name = 'TESTTABLE'
ORDER BY column_id;
```

Test Case:

```
CREATE TABLE testtable
(
    batchid   INTEGER
  , col1      INTEGER
  , col2      INTEGER
);

BEGIN
    FOR batchid IN 1 .. 3
    LOOP
        FOR col1 IN 1 .. 3
        LOOP
            FOR col2 IN 1 .. 2
            LOOP
                INSERT INTO testtable
                     VALUES (batchid, col1, col2);
            END LOOP;
        END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Execute the SQL and you generate the following SQL statement:

```
select 'batchid: ' || batchid 
     || case when COL1<> lag(COL1) over (partition by batchid order by col1, col2) then ' COL1 has changed' end
     || case when COL2<> lag(COL2) over (partition by batchid order by col1, col2) then ' COL2 has changed' end as changemessage from testtable
```

I will leave it to you to reduce the result set:

```
CHANGEMESSAGE
batchid: 1
batchid: 1
batchid: 1
batchid: 1
batchid: 1 COL2 has changed
batchid: 1
batchid: 1
batchid: 1
batchid: 1 COL1 has changed COL2 has changed
batchid: 1
batchid: 1
batchid: 1
batchid: 1 COL2 has changed
batchid: 1
batchid: 1
batchid: 1
batchid: 1 COL1 has changed COL2 has changed
batchid: 1
batchid: 1
batchid: 1
batchid: 1 COL2 has changed
batchid: 1
batchid: 1
batchid: 1
batchid: 2
batchid: 2
batchid: 2
batchid: 2
batchid: 2 COL2 has changed
batchid: 2
batchid: 2
batchid: 2
batchid: 2 COL1 has changed COL2 has changed
batchid: 2
batchid: 2
batchid: 2
batchid: 2 COL2 has changed
batchid: 2
batchid: 2
batchid: 2
batchid: 2 COL1 has changed COL2 has changed
batchid: 2
batchid: 2
batchid: 2
batchid: 2 COL2 has changed
batchid: 2
batchid: 2
batchid: 2
batchid: 3
batchid: 3
batchid: 3
batchid: 3
batchid: 3 COL2 has changed
batchid: 3
batchid: 3
batchid: 3
batchid: 3 COL1 has changed COL2 has changed
batchid: 3
batchid: 3
batchid: 3
batchid: 3 COL2 has changed
batchid: 3
batchid: 3
batchid: 3
batchid: 3 COL1 has changed COL2 has changed
batchid: 3
batchid: 3
batchid: 3
batchid: 3 COL2 has changed
batchid: 3
batchid: 3
batchid: 3
```

Comment: Wow thanks Brian! The code is great example!  Thanks much!

Comment: Hi @Brian Leach, thanks again! What if I want to display the before and after update value, between the latest and the prior batch?   I want the comparison of different values to be stored in an audit trail table, with 4 main columns:   batch_id,  field_name,  current_value, previous_value. In the Field_Name, i will compare about 600 columns such as income, height, address_state, etc... how to make sure that the difference of these information is captured?  Thanks again!

Comment: @LycorisRadiata You can adjust the generated select statement to perform an insert. I would not store the before/after values, but rather the primary key that would point to the appropriate records. A view could then display before/after values however you want.

Comment: Thanks @Brian Leach...  yeah, the business requirement is to store the before and after values in an audit table with primary key and distinguishable person_id etc.. The business ask is to have all the changes made to the columns stored in a table...